# Calling a c++ function

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to c++ and i have been trying to use the librow library (median filter). What i could not understand is the following:

```
typedef int element;
```

It says that it is an int. But here:

```
//   2D MEDIAN FILTER, window size 3x3
//     image  - input image
//     result - output image, NULL for inplace processing
//     N      - width of the image
//     M      - height of the image
void medianfilter(element* image, element* result, int N, int M);
```

It says to put the image as type element*. How is this possible? An example in your answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem? result/image are a POINTERS to an element...

Comment: @MarcB The problem I see, is that `element* result` needs to be appropriately pre-allocated (or `NULL`), to make sense of this function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer can point to a single element, or it can point to an *array* of elements. The compiler doesn't care one way or the other. In this case you're expected to pass an array.

When you pass a pointer to an array, you must also pass information that gives you the size of the array. In this case it would be `N * M`.

Answer (score 0):

`element*` means a pointer to an int. Aka the address in memory of an `int` variable.
In this case it would be the address of an array of ints (i.e. the first int in a list of sequential ints.)
Each of the N*M ints would represent a pixel of the image, row by row.

Comment: Sorry, i may not understand correctly, i thought it would want from me to give something like "image1.bmp". can you please clarify?

Comment: You first need to load the file into an in-memory `int*` buffer using some library, and then apply the function to that.